# Setting up a DNS and pointing a domain on my new Virtual Server (Windows 2008)

Tags: dns, hosting, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm a newbie to hosting. Please bear with me.

I bought a new Virtual Server with my host GoDaddy. I want to setup my own DNS and point one or more domains to that server.

I have 3 IP addresses allocated to me. Lets assume them to be 10.0.0.1, 10.0.0.2 and 10.0.0.3. Lets assume the name of my server is "mydomain". This is what it shows when I right click on My Computer and go to Properties and see Full Computer Name. I have already installed the DNS role on this server.

What I want is to create DNS like ns1.mydomain.com and ns2.mydomain.com. Then I want to configure www.otherdomain.com to this server.

Can someone guide me on how to do the above.

Many Thanks,
Arun

Comment: Why not just use godaddy DNS?

Comment: How do I point www.otherdomain.com to my new server using GoDaddy's DNS?

Comment: Thanks Chris, I just had to change the IP Address in my control panel of my domain to the new server. This is all I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to host the DNS on your own server you will have to register your nameservers with your domain registrar first.  If this is Go Daddy you will use these steps:

1. Log in to your Account Manager.
2. Next to Domains, click Launch.
3. Click the domain name you want to use to register as your own nameserver.
4. In the Host Summary section, click add.
5. In Host name, enter the host name you want to register.  This would be something like "ns1".  The value entered here will be appended to your domain name to create the host name. Do not use the 'www' prefix. Example: For the domain name coolexample.com, entering 'ns1' here results in ns1.coolexample.com.
6. In the Host IP fields, enter the IP address for your server.
7. Click OK.

Once you have the two nameservers setup you can point your domains to the server using these.  You will need to ensure that the Zone File for the domain you setup the nameservers on will have A records for ns1 and ns2 as well.  If you host the domain on your server you would edit the Zone File on the server and add those A records.  If you do not point the nameserver domain to your server you would just to this in the DNS editor in the Domain Manager.